# OneSignal Dashboard showing "Calypso AppCrawler (6.0.1)" entries, What are those and how to exclude them

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, web-crawler, onesignal, google-crawlers

I have and ionic, cordova hybrid mobile app on play store and i have used OneSignal for handling Push Notifications in mobile app. I have noticed from OneSignal Dashboard, there are lots of  "Calypso AppCrawler" entries without Push Token being generated(refer to attached screenshot).

Does anyone knows what are those entries and how do i exclude them from OneSignal Dashboard?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the second part of the question (excluding them from OneSignal dash) - but those entries are Google's App Indexing crawlbot, and the devices they are set up with never generate an FCM token.